# Similarly to boost::mpl::if_ in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, metaprogramming

Is there a replacement for `boost::mpl::if_` in C++?
I do not have the opportunity to use boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::conditional` [(C++11) should fit your needs.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)
Probably you can use it as drop-in replacement.

Comment: Note that `mpl::if_` takes a *type* as the condition, `std::conditional` is equivalent to `mpl::if_c` which takes a `bool` as the condition.

Comment: @melak47, it is now fairly easy to transform type constants into value constants and vice versa. `constexpr auto v = Type::value` or `= Type{}` and `using t = std::intergral_constant<bool, Value>`, or `= std::bool_constant<Value>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Boost 1.66, [Boost.MP11](https://www.boost.org/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) is a C++11 metaprogramming library available as replacement where *[Boost.MPL is no longer good enough](http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html)*. Boost.MP11 provides `mp_if`.

Comment: Didn't know about this, I was waiting for it for a while. I find strange that it sticks an `mp_` prefix to everything (!?).

Comment: There is a reason. Search for this question "Why the mp_ prefix?" in http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html